# Parent resides in datastore, assign children uploaded using CSV bulkloader

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, parent, bulkloader

Presently I have a `Team` residing in the datastore:

```
team = Team.get_by_key_name('Plants')
```

And I have the following CSV file in my local computer:

```
name,level
Pea Shooter,1
Threepeater,3
Melon-pult,20
```

My `bulkloader.yaml` looks like this:

```
python_preamble:
- import: models
- import: my_transforms

transformers:
- kind: Character
  connector: csv
  property_map:
  - property: name
    external_name: name

  - property: level
    external_name: level
    import_transform: my_transforms.transform_integer
```

I wrote a `models.py` that looks like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Team(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()

class Character(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  level = db.IntegerProperty()
```

I also wrote a `my_transforms.py`:

```
def transform_integer(integer_string):
  return int(integer_string)
```

**Question:**  How do I upload the CSV file so that when the `Character`s enter the datastore, their `parent` properties are assigned to `team`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer lacks detail but I was able to glean some information from it.

I added another column to my CSV file named `Character.csv`:

```
team,name,level
Plants,Pea Shooter,1
Plants,Threepeater,3
Plants,Melon-pult,20
```

The `bulkloader.yaml` now looks like this:

```
python_preamble:
- import: models
- import: my_transforms

transformers:
- kind: Character
  connector: csv
  property_map:
  - property: __key__
    external_name: team
    import_transform: transform.create_deep_key(('Team', 'team', False),
                                                ('Character', 'name', False))

  - property: name
    external_name: name

  - property: level
    external_name: level
    import_transform: my_transforms.transform_integer
```

Then I do the following in the Terminal:

```
$ cd /path/to/app
$ appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml \
                        --filename=Character.csv \
                        --kind=Character \
                        --url=http://localhost:8082/_ah/remote_api
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same as @Kit: assign parent on bulkload. I've successfully uploaded the parent entities, but having trouble uploading the children as I don't understand `import_transform: transform.create_deep_key`. I think you've solved it, but I'm not smart enough to understand what you've done, or what it means. Could you explain your solution? Specifically, I don't know the purpose of `False` or what the bulkloader is doing with your `Team`, `team` values. Could you explain what you've done for us dummies? Thanks, T.

Comment: Ah, think I get it, from [googleappengine code](http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py):  

  Args:
    path_info: List of tuples, describing (kind, property, is_id=False).
      ...
      **is_id: Converts value to int** and treats as numeric ID if True, otherwise the value is a string name. Default is False.

  Returns:
    Transform method which parses the info from the current neutral dictionary into a Key with parents as described by path_info.

Answer (score 1):

The parent information is stored in the key, so you would set the `__key__` property.

In order to create a multi-level key, you would need to use `google.appengine.ext.bulkload.transform.create_deep_key`, which takes `path_info` as an argument and returns a transform method that parses the current dict into a Key with the parents you specify in `path_info`.  For more information read the docstring in the actual method, which can be found in `APPENGINE_ROOT/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py`, or the latest version of the file off the repo is [here](http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py).

Answer (score 1):

Small point - you can use the statement below instead if your "my_transforms.transform_integer"

```
import_transform: 'lambda x: int(x)'
```